# .Net 4.5 Await Breakpoints

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, breakpoints, async-await

I couldn't find a full example for PostAsync so I had to piece one together.  Therefore, I am not sure if what I am viewing is a limitation with the debugger or I simply did it wrong.

**This is what I am trying to do:**

I have to go through a list and make a web service call for each item on the list. My thought is that I could use the new 4.5 async stuff to keep it flowing without blocking during each call to the web service.

I've done a tone of research and watched Jon Skeet's video on TekPub, but I'm still not sure if I am doing this correctly.  That is, when I set break points my async method never returns control to the caller.  It basically seems to go along exactly as my synchronous version.

**Question:**

Is it normal for the debugger to appear synchronous or does that indicate my code is not implemented correctly?

**Here is my Post method:**

```
Public Async Function PostSecureXMLAsync(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal XMLtoSend As String) As Task(Of String)

    Dim content = New StringContent(XMLtoSend, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")

    Dim credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)
    Dim handler = New HttpClientHandler() With {.Credentials = credentials}

    Using client = New HttpClient(handler)

        Using response = client.PostAsync(APIurl, content).Result
            Return Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using

    End Using

End Function
```

**This is how it is being used:**

```
For Each ListItem In ListObj
...
Result = XMLExchangeObj.PostSecureXMLAsync(Username, Password, Payload).Result
...
Next
```

I was expecting control to return to the For Each loop while it was waiting for replies from the Web Service, but based on my break points it seems to be running synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with `Async`, you don't want to call `Wait` or `Result`. Instead, you should use `Await`. I see one `Result` in `PostSecureXMLAsync`:

```
Using client = New HttpClient(handler)
    Using response = Await client.PostAsync(APIurl, content) ' Changed to Await
        Return Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    End Using
End Using
```

And there's another one when you call your `Async` method:

```
Result = Await XMLExchangeObj.PostSecureXMLAsync(Username, Password, Payload)
```

This does mean that your calling method must also be `Async`, which means any methods that call *that* method should use `Await`, and must also be `Async`, etc. This "growth" through your code is perfectly normal. Just allow `Async` to grow until you reach a natural stopping point (usually an event handler, which you can make `Async Sub`).

Comment: That is half of the puzzle because my code was incorrect. Thank you very much for fixing it. Now that it is correct and giving control back to the caller it's still not what I expected.  It waits for the first web service call to complete before going to the next item on the list.  Should I be using something else aside from async (such as Parallel.ForEach) if I want the loop to issue calls in parallel?  Essentially, I want to issue all the web service calls at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: You can start them all executing at once by calling `PostSecureXMLAsync` and saving the task instead of `Awaiting` it (you can do this either with a `For Each` loop building a list of tasks, or with a LINQ `Select` expression). Once you have a list of tasks (which are already executing), you can `Await` that via `Task.WhenAll`: `Results = Await Task.WhenAll(taskList)`. The result value is an array of strings.

Comment: Wow! Good stuff. Thank you.